# better method to aggregate pandas dataframe by non matching criteria

Tags: python, aggregation, pandas

I have a `dataframe` of species survey counts and need to aggregate the rows by multiple criteria. The main problem is that I need to match seasonal samples across different years. For example a spring 2005 sample will be matched to an autumn 2006 sample where the site sample method and replicates match. Here is a simple example of the data:

```
# create the factors and dataframe
a = repeat('AAA',4)
b = repeat('BBB',2)
y1 = np.array([2005, 2006])
y2 = np.array([2005, 2007])
r = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 1 , 1])
d = {'site' : hstack((a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b)),
     'year' : hstack((y1, y1, y1, y2, y2, y2, y1, y1, y1, y2, y2, y2)),
     'season' : hstack((repeat('AUTUMN', 6), repeat('SPRING', 6), repeat('AUTUMN', 6), repeat('SPRING', 6))),
     'method' : hstack((repeat('EDGE', 12), repeat('RIFFLE', 12))),
     'replicate' : hstack((r, r, r, r))}
df = DataFrame(d)

# now add some species
df['sp1'] = 1
df['sp2'] = 2
df['sp3'] = 3
```

Each row in the dataframe is a singe sample. Currently I am creating a new merged 'id' column, iterating through each of the 'SPRING' samples searching for a matching autumn sample and updating this 'id' for both samples before grouping on the 'id'. for example:

```
df['id'] = 'na' # new column for combined season id
grouped = df.groupby('season') # split table by season 

for name, group in grouped:
    if name == 'AUTUMN':
        aut = group #autumn lookup list
    if name == 'SPRING':
        # for each spring sample
        for row_index, row in group.iterrows():
            # check for matching autumn sample
            n = aut[
                (aut['site'] == row['site']) &
                (aut['year'] == row['year'] + 1) &
                (aut['method'] == row['method']) &
                (aut['replicate'] == row['replicate'])].index
            if n:
                # create new combined season id
                new_id = row['site'] + \
                         str(row['year'])[-2:] + \
                         str(row['year'] + 1)[-2:] + \
                         row['method'][:1] + \
                         str(row['replicate'])
                # update id spring sample with matching autumn 
                df.id.ix[row_index] = new_id
                # get matching autumn table index
                df.id.ix[n] = new_id
df = df[df['id'] != 'na']
combined = df.groupby(['method', 'id', 'site']).sum()
combined = combined.drop(['year', 'replicate'], axis=1)
```

This methods works quite well but I think it is a bit clunky and is not at all versatile. Is there a vectorised way to aggregate data in this way? Sorry for the length of the post and please let me know if anything is unclear.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: corrected code

How about this:

```
adjyear = np.where(df.season == 'SPRING', df.year + 1, df.year)
adjyear.name = 'year'

grouped = df.groupby(['method', 'replicate', 'site', adjyear])
grouped = grouped['sp1', 'sp2', 'sp3']    

grouped.sum()[grouped.size() > 1]
```

This gives me:

```
In [20]: grouped.sum()[grouped.size() > 1]
Out[20]: 
                            sp1  sp2  sp3
method replicate site year               
EDGE   1         AAA  2006    2    4    6
                 BBB  2006    2    4    6
       2         AAA  2006    2    4    6
RIFFLE 1         AAA  2006    2    4    6
                 BBB  2006    2    4    6
       2         AAA  2006    2    4    6
```